# How to return filtered array with vuex getters?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuex

I try to return filtered array with VUEX getters but it send me this

```
ƒ (region) {
    return state.cities.filter(function (city) {
      return city.region === region;
    });
  }
```

I dont understud why it happend; hope somebody could help me.
My code

***VUEX:***

```
getCities: state => region => {
        return state.cities.filter(city => city.region === region);
    }
```

***App.vue***

```
test(a){
  console.log(this.getCities(a))
}
```

Comment: Check this: https://renatello.com/vuex-vuejs-getters/#Vuejs_example_using_Vuex_store_getter

Comment: What is ```getCities: state => region => {```? I think it should be ```getCities(state) {``` and "region" should be in the state object too.

Comment: try out to append `()` like `console.log(this.getCities(a)())` to run the getter method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the solution. The right way to call VUEX getters with params should be `this.$store.getters.yourGetter()(params)` or with ...mapGetters. The main point that the getters with params return function and you can pass params in it.
For example how it works

**getter:**

```
getCities: state => region => {
    return state.cities.filter(city => city.region === region);
}
```

**import and call:**

```
methods: {
...mapGetters('location', [ 'getCities' ]),
test(params){
  console.log(this.getCities()(params))
}
}
```

Comment: that was what I answered for you

Comment: Sorry, but your answer did not work for me(

Answer (score 0):

You can import mapGetters or access the store object through this.$store.getters.getCities(a)

you can read more here:

https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/getters.html#property-style-access